# ADF REST API , getting exception

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, weblogic12c, jdeveloper

Am newbie to ADF framework. Am developing a REST API by using this framework, and it works perfectly in integrated WebLogic on JDeveloper 12c (12.2.1), but in the production environment am getting an exception while performing the request. I feel like am missing some library in WebLogic.

production URL: http://192.168.2.4:7001/EcomCMS-RESTWebService-context-root/rest/CMS_API/ecomBill/01/child/EcomBillVO?finder=orderRowFinder;OrderNo=2017/156

server log :

```
<Mar 15, 2018, 10:01:05,953 AM AST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@741490999[app:EcomCMS_Project1_EcomCMS module:EcomCMS-RESTWebService-context-root path:null spec-version:3.1]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.adf.internal.model.rest.core.http.header.HeaderConfiguratorInfo.setSuppressedHeaders(Ljava/util/Set;)V
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.rest.ResourceServlet.execute(ResourceServlet.java:268)
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.rest.ResourceServlet.doGet(ResourceServlet.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.rest.ResourceServlet.service(ResourceServlet.java:135)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace>
<Mar 15, 2018, 10:01:05,966 AM AST> <Notice> <Diagnostics> <BEA-320068> <Watch "UncheckedException" in module "Module-FMWDFW" with severity "Notice" on server "AdminServer" has triggered at Mar 15, 2018 10:01:05 AM AST. Notification details:
WatchRuleType: Log
WatchRule: (SEVERITY = 'Error') AND ((MSGID = 'WL-101020') OR (MSGID = 'WL-101017') OR (MSGID = 'WL-000802') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-101020') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-101017') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-000802'))
WatchData: MESSAGE = [ServletContext@741490999[app:EcomCMS_Project1_EcomCMS module:EcomCMS-RESTWebService-context-root path:null spec-version:3.1]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.adf.internal.model.rest.core.http.header.HeaderConfiguratorInfo.setSuppressedHeaders(Ljava/util/Set;)V
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.rest.ResourceServlet.execute(ResourceServlet.java:268)
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.rest.ResourceServlet.doGet(ResourceServlet.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.rest.ResourceServlet.service(ResourceServlet.java:135)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at oracle.wsm.agent.handler.servlet.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:321)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
 SUPP_ATTRS = {severity-value=8, rid=0, partition-id=0, partition-name=DOMAIN} SERVER = AdminServer TIMESTAMP = 1521097265953 USERID = <WLS Kernel> MACHINE = WIN-L4R7T5PSL2G MSGID = BEA-101017 DATE = Mar 15, 2018, 10:01:05,953 AM AST SUBSYSTEM = HTTP CONTEXTID = 0556875b-2ef3-4871-93b2-3427f3afa4e8-0000007d TXID =  SEVERITY = Error THREAD = [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '16' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
WatchAlarmType: AutomaticReset
WatchAlarmResetPeriod: 30000>
<Mar 15, 2018, 10:01:06,776 AM AST> <Emergency> <oracle.dfw.incident> <BEA-000000> <incident 25 created with problem key "DFW-99998 [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError][oracle.adf.model.servlet.rest.ResourceServlet.execute][EcomCMS_Project1_EcomCMS]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the ADF Runtime on your stand-alone WebLogic?
How did you create the EAR file for your REST service deployment? Did you include the model project in that ear file as a dependency?